# How can upstream onComplete propagate to flatmapped observable downstream?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

```
observable1
 .filter { ... }
 .flatMap { observable2 }
 .doFinally {  }
```

if my upstream observable1 completes, observable2 keeps still chugging along and my doFinally doesnt get called

How can I make observable2 complete when upstream completes?

// Working example

```
Observable.just(1)
                .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d("Default", "upstream completed"))
                .flatMap(__ -> Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .subscribe(
                        __ -> Log.d("Default", "onNext"),
                        t -> Log.d("Default", "onError"),
                        () -> Log.d("Default", "onComplete"));
```

Comment: @Anatolii sorry I dont get what you mean, but here is an actual example

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work, combination of `doFinally` and `takeUntil` - probably other ways of doing the same thing, not sure of your use case though, seems a little odd to do this :

```
    var boolean = false

    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(schedulerA))
            .doFinally { println("Do Finally before flatMap"); boolean = true }
            .observeOn(Schedulers.from(schedulerB))
            .flatMap { Observable.just(it) }
            .takeUntil { boolean }
            .subscribe { println(it) }
```